# Unit Tests, Creating Data Source - StringConnections in VS2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, connection-string, datasource

Can someone tutorial me how to create DataSource from Excel File linked wih Unit Test in VS2013? In VS2010 it was possible to open Project -> Test View and then Properties. Now that option is not possible.
I tried MSDN help and so on but I cant do that.
I would like to reach sh like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/testy-jednostkowe-w-visual-studio.aspx between image 16 and 17.
Thank you for help

I know how Create new Data source but I do not know how to use it in [DataSource()]

```
[TestClass()]
public class OperationsTests
{
    private TestContext context;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return context; }
        set { context = value; }
    }

    [DeploymentItem("1.xls")]
    [DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", @"Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=.\1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5", "Arkusz1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    [TestMethod()]
    public void AddTest()
    {
        Operations target = new Operations();
        int a = Int32.Parse(context.DataRow["A"].ToString());
        int b = Int32.Parse(context.DataRow["B"].ToString());
        int expected = Int32.Parse(context.DataRow["Wynik"].ToString());             
        int actual;                         
        actual = target.Add(a, b);          
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);  
    }
}
```

Comment: May be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538340/data-driven-unit-test-from-excel-spreadsheet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684441/vs-team-test-net-unit-testing-with-excel-as-data-source-adapter-failed

Comment: Thanks, i saw that page earlier but when i added DeploymentItem and DataSource from finger and RunTests nothing happened.

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Comment: Try to Debug your test. in VS 2013: TEST -> Debug -> Selected Test. It looks like failure occurs before reaching  Assert.AreEqual

Comment: Do you set your context before using?

Comment: Ok i corrected sth and know it said Cannot connect to data source. Should i create DataSource?

Comment: It can be different reasons of this error: Access denied, File Not Exists etc. Please get Message of your exception. For do it use try-catch statement.

Comment: Can you tell me if creating Data Source by Project - New Data SOurce is nessesery?
About error : in the MSDN library, Error details[IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Cannot fint data source name, and default driver didnt define

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1040141.aspx?Data+source+name+not+found+and+no+default+driver+specified+When+the+website+was+published+but+not+error+when+I+run+it+in+debug+mode+VS+NET+2005+

Comment: Sorry that didnt help me...
i created a new project. i copied Operation class and OperationTests class and now i have a problem with context.DataRow everyone is underlined and error (Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Data.DataRow)

Comment: Ok That was my mistake i hadnt reference to System.Data and know the same problem IM002. i even write full path in dbq and nothing new

Comment: Problem solved
Data Source should looks like that
[DataSource("System.Data.OleDB",@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|'; Excel 8.0;HDR=YES","Arkusz1$",DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]