# How to specify datasource in data-driven unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, data-driven-tests

I have written a data-driven unit test and now I need to specify the data source for the unit test. The unit test is written in C# with MS Visual Studio. My data source is an excel file with a sheet named "TestData". My code for data source is as follows:

```
[DataSource(
        "System.Data.Odbc",
        "Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=.\data.xlsx;defaultdir=.; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5",
        "TestData$",
        "Sequential"
    )]
```

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What's your problem with this? Raise any error? [DataSourceAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't meet the constructor of DataSource. However, I found this [DataSource(
    dataProvider, 
    connectionString, 
    tableName,
    dataAccessMethod
    )] at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx#bkmk_creating_a_data_source

Comment: This question has already been resolved. Please refer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538340/data-driven-unit-test-from-excel-spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put ConnectionString in Config file and add to Attribute

```
<connectionStrings>  
     <add name="MyExcelConn" connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=.\data.xlsx;defaultdir=.; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Then add to your update your attribute:

```
[DataSource("MyExcelDataSource")]
```

Comment: Should be the `MyExcelDataSource` be `MyExcelConn` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run **Visual Studio Data Source Wizard** to run the tests. [Click here to See the Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_RADqzNO0g)